# Installing & running a python script on Ubuntu

Tags: server, 10.04, python, apache2

I have a (most likely very stupid) question to ask: I recently setup a fresh install of Ubuntu 10.04 to use as an internal web server for some very basic tasks. I came across [a python script](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipcalc) that I want to serve up from this box.

It's a relatively basic script and I'm sure a relatively basic process to serve it up from apache web server. I want to learn for the sake of learning. Any/all help anyone can provide would be very appreciated.

I guess it's worth noting that I have complete and unrestricted access to this box. (Forgive me for doing this, but I have enabled root access *cringe&shutter*)

McGonigiggle

Comment: either cd to its directory first, then python filename.py, or python /path/filename.py

Answer (score 1):

from a commandline;

python **FILENAME**.py

then just enter. Then you should get an installation screen.